# Angular ui grid restore state not working

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid, savestate

I'm trying to save the state of an angular grid so when you go back to the grid the user can restore where you left it.

I get no errors when I click save or restore.

The grid does not change when you click restore after you save the grid.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$scope.saveState = function(){
     console.log("Saving")
     var state = $scope.gridApi.saveState.save();
     $window.localStorage.setItem('gridState', state);
     console.log("Saving done")
};

$scope.restoreState = function(){
    console.log("Restoring")
    var state = $window.localStorage.getItem('gridState');
    if (state) $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore($scope, state);
    console.log("Restoring done")
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem I found out that `$window.localStorage` can not save objects.

To work around this you can use `JSON.stringify`

```
  $scope.saveState = function(){
        console.log("Saving")
        var state = $scope.gridApi.saveState.save();
        console.log(state)
        $window.localStorage.setItem('gridState', JSON.stringify(state));
        console.log("Saving done")
   };

   function restoreState(){
        console.log("Restoring")
        $timeout(function() {
           var state = $window.localStorage.getItem('gridState');
           console.log(state)
           if (state) $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore($scope, JSON.parse(state));
        });
        console.log("Restoring done")
   };
```